# Adding Pydev to my plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, pydev

I'm developing an Eclipse RCP plugin and I need to add a Python editor to my plugin. This Python editor should have auto indentation and code analysis for compilation errors. I've searched the Internet and found Pydev as the best option but I can't find any extension point of it to add it to my project. Does any one know how can I add Pydev to my plugin and is there any other Python editor available for eclipse that I can use them in my plugin?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only distribute the PyDev plugin along with your RCP application (and when you open a .py file ask to open with the PyDev editor ID) -- you don't really need any special extension point for that.

Comment: Is there any way to distribute it with my plugin except for copying the jar file to the plugin folder?

Comment: You can download its source code and bundle it into your plugin if you want (but if the user also has a separate install of pydev, things may go awry).